# Accessing json's elements with Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter

I use this code to load my file:

```python
with open('filepath') as myfile:

    data = [next(myfile) for x in xrange(100)]

print data

print json.dumps(data, indent=1, sort_keys=False)
```

In the first case the structure I get, looks like:

```
[

'{"A": "Avalue", "B": "Bvalue", "C": [c1, c2], "D": "Dvalue"}\n',

'{"2A": "2Avalue", "2B": "2Bvalue", "2C": [2c1, 2c2], "2D": "2Dvalue"}\n'

]
```

In the second case:

```
[

  "{\"A": \"Avalue\", \"B\": \"Bvalue\", \"C\": [c1, c2], \"D\": value\"D\"}\n", 

  "{\"2A": \"2Avalue\", \"2B\": \"2Bvalue\", \"2C\": [2c1, 2c2], \"2D\": 2value\"D\"}\n"}

]
```

I am trying to get access to its elements, but I can't figure out how. Does anyone know about the meaning of the slashes and can help me.
Thanks

Comment: I work on jupyter

Comment: Don't use json.dumps() on your data variable.

Answer (score 1):

This file is encoded twice in JSON.

In case you're using `json.dumps()` on a JSON file or if you use `json.dumps()` twice, then this will happen. Can you show us more about it?

Possible solution:

```
import json
clear_json = json.loads(your_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 string elements in the list: `\"` just means you have `"` characters in your string (in other words there is a `"` character inside the string).